# Identify almost-Superman novel about "The Man in Crimson & Cream"

Tags: story-identification, novel, superman

I read this novel probably in the 1980s or 1990s.  The POV character is a reporter who investigates an almost-Superman character referred to as "The Man in Crimson & Cream".  He has Superman's powers and weaknesses, but is never referred to as Superman.  If I remember correctly the almost-Superman was having some kind of mid-life crisis where he was creating dangerous situations for people who he would then save at the last minute.   I think he wore special glasses which altered his features so that others could not identify his alter ego (i.e., adding a little more plausibility to Clark Kent's plain glasses).  The novel also refers to "a certain mineral that affects his powers", again an indirect reference to Kryptonite.

Google searches for "the man in crimson & cream" were unsuccessful.